# How can I make folders in my custom directory and create create a folder in /myapp/documents in advance(when I build the app)?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I'm making a vocabulary application for iOS and ipadOS. The structure is

Folders(IELTS, TOPFL, etc) -> Vocabularies(Cambridge IELTS, Oxford IELTS, etc) -> words(play, sleep, etc)

The Vocabularies file will be .txt file, so I can make it like

["word1" : "meaning1"], ["word1", "meaning2"], ....

And I want to make Folders file when users install the app.

So it would be my app/documents/folders

But when I install the app, it becomes my app/documents/, no folders.

Is there something like install script on iOS?

And the second question is when I create folder

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let docURL = URL(string: documentsDirectory)!
let dataPath = docURL.appendingPathComponent(String(AddNewFolder.text!)) // AddNewFolder is a Text Field
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString) {
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription);
    }
}
```

How can I create new folder in myapp/documents/folders, not /myapp/documents?

Third question is about UIKit vs SwiftUI. What is faster and what is easier to use?

And in SwiftUI, there are SwiftUI App and UIKit delegate and what is UIKit delegate?(Does that mean that I use UIKit in SwiftUI?)

Comment: One options to create the folder in code instead. Check if the folder exists when the app is started and otherwise create it.

Comment: How can see the whole directory? Files only shows icloud and user directories, not applications, /etc, /usr, /var, etc. Is there an app to navigate the whole file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I googled a whole week. The answer is

```
// make subdirectory "vocabFolder" if it doesn't exist
let VocabFolderPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("vocabFolder")

if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: VocabFolderPath.absoluteString) {
    try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: VocabFolderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
    
// create custom vocab folder
let CustomVocabFolderPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("vocabFolder/\(String(AddNewFolder.text!))")
    
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: CustomVocabFolderPath.absoluteString) {
    try! FileManager.default.createDirectory(at: CustomVocabFolderPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
}
```

and to navigate a Simualtor device, execute
`open 'xcrun simctl get_app_container booted BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER data' -a Finder`